# UICollectionView won't show images after downloading - Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard

I have a DetailViewController that is segued to when you click on a table view cell , the detail view shows a label , rating and a collectionView , the UICollectionView setup like this , ideally it should show two images that are downloaded and put into the image array

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var LabelView: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var RatingsView: CosmosView!
    
    var mv : Result?
    
    var imgArr = [UIImage]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        LabelView.text = mv?.title
        RatingsView.rating = Double((mv!.vote_average / 2))
        
        let uri = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + mv!.poster_path
        downloadImage(with : uri){image in
            guard let image  = image else { return}
            self.imgArr.append(image)
        }

        let bUri = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + mv!.backdrop_path
        downloadImage(with : bUri){image in
            guard let image  = image else { return}
            self.imgArr.append(image)
            dump(self.imgArr)
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imgImage.image = imgArr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func downloadImage(with urlString : String , imageCompletionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void){
            guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString) else {
                return  imageCompletionHandler(nil)
            }
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url)
            
            KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: resource, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let value):
                    imageCompletionHandler(value.image)
                case .failure:
                    imageCompletionHandler(nil)
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Here is what it looks like in storyboard , I have the proper classes and reuseIdentifiers assigned

[image]

But I can't see any images for some reason
[image]

I have no clue why it won't show the images , it did before I changed the layout to add a master stack view , but I can't figure out why a minor layout change would affect , I still think i'm doing something wrong in the code. I tried adding .reloadData() and other troubleshooting but it didn't work.
The images are downloading as seen in the output dump which prints when you segue to the detail view.

[image]

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are cell's images has width and height? I had same issue and I noticed that width and height values were missing. I can suggest you to check width and height values after updating cells.

Answer (score 0):

You should always update anything on UI on the main thread. Please add your returned image inside DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Comment: im not sure I follow , I have updated the code to add the reload and append lines inside the dispatch queue , but it doesn't work                                                   `

Comment: Ok I had not seen your response earlier, sorry about that @Harvindersingh. What I wanted to say is that you need to get the updated array of the images in the viewDidLoad through a closure or a handler and when you received it make sure to call the tableview's reloadData on the main thread along with the data received there.

Comment: So in your case it will be like this:

`DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
   self?.imgArr.append(image)
   self? collectionView.reloadData()
}` 

// Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly -- the problem is that the collection view loads ***before*** the images are downloaded.

In `viewDidLoad()` you start an async process of downloading two images. That will take "some time" -- it might take 1/4 second, 1/2 second... or it may be very quick (if they are small images) and only take 1/10th of a second.

However, `numberOfItemsInSection` is probably being called at **1/100th of a second** - well before the images have been downloaded.

Change that to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("number of images:", imgArr.count)
    return imgArr.count

}
```

and you'll likely see `number of images: 0` as the output.

In your completion block(s), you need to add:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Note also... those two images won't necessarily download consecutively. If you need them in **that order**, you will either want to:

- download the first image, then in its completion block start downloading the second image, or
- start with two "placeholder" images in your `imgArr` and then replace them in the desired order

In any case, you'll still need to call `.reloadData()` *after* the images have downloaded.